# writing if statement in excel in mac (output error)

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I am writing = if(G2<32, "YES", "NO")
Rather than printing yes or no in cells, when i hit enter, it is just printing if(G2<32, "YES", "NO") the same formula again and again. i dont understand what is wrong

Comment: Is that really all that is in the cell? No extra spaces or other non visible characters? How is the cell formatted? A screencap of the cell and the formula bar may be useful here

Comment: Please share us with a screenshot to show the formula that in formula bar.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options (I tested them using exel 2021):

### 1. Format bug

I've witnessed a similar bug a few times: if you set first the cell (or better the whole sheet) to text, then paste the formula `= if(G2<32, "YES", "NO")` , you sometimes just see the formula and not the result. You can then set the format to general, but it doesn't change, somehow the cells stay stuck in text format.
Then you can copy paste it so, and you only get the formula.
Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> to recalculate the whole sheet doesn't work (the formulas don't get calculated, they stay stuck in text mode).Something like this:

[image]

If you go to each cell, edit them (click or <kbd>F2</kbd>) and press enter, then it calculates them again, and you see the result.
Maybe you copied cells from another file that were set as text and that got carried over?

### 2. Show Formula enabled

In the ribbon under *Formulas* there is an option *Show Formulas*. If you select it, then you only see the formulas, and not the results:

[image]